# what should be return type of a query which fetches 2 columns in spring data neo4j?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have following query which i use through @Query annotation with GraphRepository in spring data neo4j. So to get a result i declare return type of method as List

```
@Query(value = "START user=node:searchByMemberID(memberID=1) MATCH user-[r:FRIENDS_WITH]->member RETURN member")
List<Node> getNodes(int userID);
```

Now if i want to write a query which returns 2 columns, what will be the return type of its corresponding method. For e.g. what should i write in place of List, as in above query, for the below mentioned query.

```
START user=node:searchByMemberID(memberID='1') MATCH user-[r:FRIENDS_WITH]->member RETURN member, r.property
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In that case queries return an `Iterable<Map<String,Object>>` which allows you to iterate over the returned rows. Each element is a map which you can access by the name of the returned field and using the *neo4jOperations* conversion method to cast the value object to its proper class, i.e.:

```
Iterable<Map<String, Object>> it = getNodes(...);

while (it.hasNext()) {
   Map<String, Object> map = it.next();
   obj = neo4jOperations.convert(map.get("member"), Node.class);
   ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for a prompt reply. Can you tell me how to create neo4jOperations object as Neo4jOperations is an interface and i am struggling a bit to convert object to Node.

Comment: It's injected by Spring Data Neo4j using the _@Autowired_ annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do something like this in SDN:

```
@QueryResult
public class NodeData {
    Member member;
    String property;
}
```

And then in the repository:

```
@Query("The Query...")
public NodeData getNodes(int userId);
```

This was adapted from an example in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_mapresult